# How to format a string to a new string without changing the original?

Tags: python, string

I have an original string: `WORKER_TEMPLATE = "worker-{0}"` how can I use that template to create: `"worker-0"`, `"worker-2"` and `"worker-N"` most efficiently? If I simply use string formatting I will lose the original after the first formatting since it is in place. Is there a way to format a string not in place?

Comment: Neither `format` or `replace` modify the existing string, since strings are built to be immutable in Python.

Comment: When you say "If I simply use string formatting I will lose the original after the first formatting since it is in place", what do you mean exactly? Will you [edit] your question to show the code that these words describe?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice no. Since my mistake was not string related and this is a topic for another question. But I now know that my bug is in another castle that is more threading related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.format` is immutable so it won't change the original formatted string.

```py
WORKER_TEMPLATE = "worker-{0}"
for i in range(5):
    print(WORKER_TEMPLATE.format(i))
    
worker-0
worker-1
worker-2
worker-3
worker-4
```

You can also define a generator using the same formatted string:

```py
>>> def get_value(n=5):
...     for i in range(n):
...         yield WORKER_TEMPLATE.format(i)
...         
>>> values = get_value()
>>> next(values)
'worker-0'
>>> next(values)
'worker-1'
>>> next(values)
'worker-2'
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't. String is immutable in python means once assigned, it cannot be replaced. Consider this for your example:

```py
s = "worker-{0}"
s1 = s.format(1)
s2 = s.format(2)
print(s)
print(s1, s2)
```

The output will be:

> worker-{0}
>
> worker-1 worker-2

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable hence at each modification a new instance is created, see [why string are immutable](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-are-python-strings-immutable).

```
n = 5
WORKER_TEMPLATE = "worker-{}"  # <- without 0
workers = list(map(WORKER_TEMPLATE.format, range(n)))

print(workers)
#['worker-0', 'worker-1', 'worker-2', 'worker-3', 'worker-4']
```

Remark: the following are equivalents:

```
s1 = "{} & {}"  
print(s1.format('a', 'b'))
```

and

```
s2 = "{0} & {1}"  
print(s2.format('a', 'b'))
```

A possible advantage of the "place-holder" notation are multiple substitution of the same value:

```
print("{0} & {1} {0}".format('a', 'b'))
#a & b a
```